# What is the closed form of :$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{\tau(2^n-1)}{\phi(2^n-1)}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, closed-form, divisor-sum

I would like to know if this series :$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{\tau(2^n-1)}{\phi(2^n-1)}$$ 
w'd be convergent or no which it's  terms related to the euler totiont function $\phi$ and $\tau(n)$ the number of divisors of  $n$ .

As show [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(tau(2%5En-1)%2Fphi(2%5En-1),+n%3D2+to+infty) in wolfram alpha for it's partial sum equal's $2$.

**My question here is:** what is the closed form of :$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{\tau(2^n-1)}{\phi(2^n-1)}$$ if it is a convergent series

Thank you for any help

Comment: Appears to converge to approx. 2.1857485878042160, which Newcastle's inverse symbolic calculator does not associate with anything.  There isn't always any nice closed form.

Comment: A version has also been posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/254174/is-this-a-true-approximation-pi-leq-sum-n-1-infty-frac-tau2n-1-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that
$$
\phi(2^n-1) \ge C_1 \frac{ 2^n}{\log n} $$ 
for some constant $C_1$, $n$ sufficiently large, and
$$
\log \tau(2^n-1) \le C_2 \frac{n}{\log n}
$$
for some $C_2$, $n$ sufficiently large.
Hence, the terms of your series 
are less than 
$$C_3 \frac{(\log n) e^{C_2 \frac{n}{\log n}}}{2^n} = 
C_3 (\log n) e^{n \left(\frac{C_2}{\log n}-\log 2 \right)}
< C_4 (0.6^n) \log n, \text{ say,}$$
for some $C_3$, $C_4$, and $n$ sufficiently large, and so the series converges.

Calculating the first $100$ terms, I find the sum to be approximately 
$$2.18574858780421606023125753...$$ which is not found to match anything
[by the inverse symbolic calculator at Newcastle](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc).

(A good reference for these kind of bounds is Gerald Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory, Chapter 1.5.)

Comment: Thanks for that , is it fatser in the side of convergece than 1/n²  ?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, it converges like $n/2^n$.

Comment: Correction: I misread Tenenbaum: the bound I thought was on tau is actually on log tau, so the argument needed a little adjustment.

Comment: The convergence is (still) faster than $1/n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is convergent because $\tau(N)\leq2^{\log_3N}$ for $N$ odd and $3\phi(N)\geq N^{\log_54}$ for $N$ odd, so that

$$\frac{\tau(2^n-1)}{\phi(2^n-1)}\leq3\cdot(2^{\log_32-\log_54})^n.$$
(Note that $\log_32-\log_54<0$.)

I personally don't hope for a closed form.

Comment: Let $f(N) = \frac{\tau(N)}{\phi(N)}$. It is multiplicative, and $f(p^k) = \frac{k+1}{p^k-p^{k-1}}$. $f(2^k) \le \frac{4}{2^{k/2}}, f(3^k) \le \frac{3}{3^{k/2}}, f(p^k) \le \frac{1}{p^{k/2}} \implies f(N) \le \frac{12}{N^{1/2}}$